# Assembly instructions issue

Tags: assembly

Can someone please explain my how this works and why in address of `c` will be stored `3C16(base-16)` and `111100`?

PS: or atleast where can I found infos about this. I'm not familiar with this at all.

```
    x DATA 4B
    y DATA F
    c DATA 0
start LDA x
      CMP y
      JLE addr1
      ADD y
      STA c
      JMP addr2
addr1 SUB y
      STA c
addr2 STOP
      END start
```

Comment: It's an `if/then` statement that either adds or subtracts `y` to `x` and stores the result in `c`.

Comment: BTW `111100` binary is `3C` hex.

Comment: Please be more specific, which part of this don't you understand? If you're studying assembly, you should have a reference that explains each instruction.

Comment: Please add the tag for whichever CPU architecture this is.

Comment: is this 6502?  Please read the assembly tag and note that it says to tag the processor type as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code performs next IF statement:

```
IF y <= x THEN c=x-y ELSE c=x+y
```

```
    x DATA 4B
    y DATA F
    c DATA 0
start LDA x       The accumulator is loaded from x with the hex value 4Bh
      CMP y       The accumulator is compared to the value at y that holds hex value 0Fh
      JLE addr1   Because 0Fh is less than 4Bh the jump is taken
      ADD y
      STA c
      JMP addr2
addr1 SUB y       The accumulator gets the result of 4Bh - 0Fh = 3Ch
      STA c
addr2 STOP
```

The code could have been shorter with removal of a redundant `STA c`:

```
      ADD y
      JMP addr2
addr1 SUB y       The accumulator gets the result of 4Bh - 0Fh = 3Ch
addr2 STA c
      STOP
```